# Where can I get the Psiphon source code and how do I compile it on CentOS 5?

Tags: linux

No matter how much googling I do, I can't seem to find the Psiphon source code (the download page on psiphon.ca gives me a '404'). Furthermore, linux installation instructions don't seem to exist. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's open source and available on project's page, via BitBucket

https://bitbucket.org/psiphon/psiphon-circumvention-system

Comment: Still dead, @avartec.

Answer (score 2):

In [psiphon3.com](http://psiphon3.com) they told that the source of it is [here](https://bitbucket.org/psiphon/psiphon-circumvention-system/overview)

Answer (score 0):

The best I can come up with would be to post your problems here:

http://psiphon.civisec.org/forum/index.php

edit:

looks like this link works too:

http://psiphon.ca/download.php

Comment: He was looking for source download, http://psiphon.ca/sourcedownload.php which doesn't work.

Comment: Neither http://psiphon.ca/download.php or  http://psiphon.ca/sourcedownload.php links work - unless they are supposed to come up with `404 Not Found`...